# Minimalist Pytest output?

Tags: python, pytest

When I run `pytest` I get a very verbose output with ugly separators `===============================================================================================================================`

For example:

```py
======================================================================================================= test session starts =======================================================================================================
platform linux -- Python 3.6.8, pytest-5.0.1, py-1.8.0, pluggy-0.12.0
rootdir: /home/ycr/info1-labo-04
collected 1 item                                                                                                                                                                                                                  

test_armstrong.py .                                                                                                                                                                                                         [100%]

==================================================================================================== 1 passed in 0.03 seconds =====================================================================================================
```

Is it possible to get a more compact output such as:

```
...
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 3 tests in 5.63s

OK
```

Comment: Very simple: you have to make sure your tests don't fail and you will get the desired output.

Comment: @KlausD. Not really. look at my modified question

Comment: You will also have to add the `-q` argument.

Comment: @KlausD. Unfortunately when it fails I still have these `================================================================================================================================================================== FAILURES ==================================================================================================================================================================`

Comment: Well, it's a testing framework. It will tell you if and how it fails. What is you actual usecase to not see this?

Comment: The usecase is a cosmetic and minimalist output as this is a testing framework.

Comment: This might help someone: Currently, enabling [live logs](https://docs.pytest.org/en/7.1.x/how-to/logging.html#live-logs) (`log_cli = true` in `pytest.ini`) will override the quite mode and the `-q` option will be ignored.

Comment: I'm also struggling to reduce `pytest` output to a useful clean list of failed tests. Of course you want the verbose output when engaged with manual failure pursuit but there's also a use-case for just emitting the names of failed tests for scripting environmental adjustments: in my case to automatically remove a JSON file per test from a subdirectory as part of the automated test framework.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can try this pytest command

```
pytest -q --show-capture=no --disable-warnings --tb=no tests.py
```

It should show you the bare minimum of information

`-q` -> quiet output

`--show-capture=no` -> Controls how captured stdout/stderr/log is shown on failed tests.

`--disable-warnings` -> if there are any warnings don't show them

`--tb=no` -> if there are any tracebacks don't show them

---

If you are using pytest version < 6.0, you can have the option `--no-print-logs`.

Comment: `--no-print-logs` command-line option was [deprecated in version 5.4 and removed in 6.0](https://docs.pytest.org/en/7.1.x/deprecations.html?highlight=print%20logs#no-print-logs-command-line-option).

Comment: Nice, I've updated the answer to include this distinction.

Comment: `pytest -q | wc -l` returns `172` whereas `pytest -q --tb=no | wc -l` returns `10`.